# RDS proxy gives empty dropdown for database, when using RDS postgreSQL 13.2

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-rds, amazon-rds-proxy

While creating an aws RDS proxy, when i go to database dropdown it remains empty, i want to use the latest version of RDS postgreSQL 13.2. How to do this?

Comment: How did it go? Still unclear why you have the error?

Answer (score 5):

RDS postgreSQL 13.2 is **not supported** by RDS proxy. From [docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/rds-proxy.html):

> RDS for PostgreSQL – version 10.10 and higher minor versions, version 11.5 and higher minor versions, and version 12.5 and higher minor versions

Comment: It now supports 12.5 and up

Comment: It is now supporting 13.1 and minor higher versions